# Error when using readxl: 'exdir' does not exist

Tags: r, excel, import, readxl

I am trying to use readxl::read_excel to import tabular data from an excel spreadsheet (.xlsx and .xls) into R. I have had success with this function when reading spreadsheets from Desktop, but I am having trouble reading from my Documents folder now.

I tried reading both .xlsx and .xls formats of the same file and got 2 different error messages.

```
# Check the working directory
[1] "\\\\isdowfsv04/D100Home/e525902"

# Read .xlsx
specs <- read_excel("Class Specs Sept 2016.xlsx")

Error: 'exdir' does not exist

# Read .xls
specs <- read_excel("Class Specs Sept 2016.xls")

Error: path[1]="\\isdowfsv04/D100Home/e525902/Class Specs Sept 2016.xls": Access is denied
```

The second message made me think I don't have permission to read/write data here, but I create folders/files here all the time. I have even used another R library, readr package, to import .csv files from this same directory.

```
# Using readr to import .csv version of the file works fine.
specs <- read_csv("\\\\isdowfsv04/D100Home/e525902/Class Specs Sept 2016.csv")
```

Based on other posts I've seen, it seems like a permission issue, but it's unclear to me how to fix it.

I tried using Sys.setenv() to change the temporary folders location to somewhere I know I have permission to write (i.e., Desktop) because I thought readxl used these paths when reading the data. But that didn't work because I got the exact same error messages.

```
Sys.getenv(c("TEMP", "TMP"))
                                      TEMP                                        TMP 
"C:\\Users\\e525902\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"     "C:\\Users\\e525902\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"

# Change temp file paths to the Desktop
Sys.setenv(TEMP = "C:\\Users\\e525902\\Desktop")
Sys.setenv(TMP = "C:\\Users\\e525902\\Desktop")
```

I am using a PC at work and the Documents folder is actually a network drive. I have used read_excel to import .xlsx files from other network folders, but this one is giving me trouble. Below is more information on the system I'm using.

```
Sys.info()
sysname                      release                      version 
               "Windows"                      "7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1" 
                nodename                      machine                        login 
           "10004053WDT"                     "x86-64"                    "e525902" 
                    user               effective_user 
               "e525902"                    "e525902"

search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:readr"     "package:readxl"    "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
 [6] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
[11] "Autoloads"         "package:base"

# R version
version$version.string
version.string R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.  It was occurring to me when I set my working directory to the base location of the excel files, and then in the read excel, using a relative path to get to the directory.

Once I rebooted R, and instead kept my working directory as the default, and then used the full file path in the read_excel function, my exdir error went away.

Let me know if this works for you.  I was also on a network drive at work with a windows 7 64-bit system.

Comment: Yes! I actually had to change my default working directory in the Global Options because my default was a directory on the network. So, I changed my default wd to somewhere on my desktop and now I can use the full path to read excel files from any network drive. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The current working directory is displayed by the RStudio IDE within the title region of the Console pane. You can also check your current working directory by running the command `getwd()` in the console.